# UITableViewCell custom edit content

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'd like my cells to have not only the Delete button while editing but also others. So what is an actual way to do this? I've tried making own `UIView` object for `editingAccessoryView` property but the problem is being that the view appears only on direct edit (i.e. clicking Edit button in Navigation Bar) and completely ignores swipes across a cell. Also `tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:` method was given a try but didn't work, at least I didn't manage to figure out how to get what I want with its function. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Try This Code

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 UITableViewRowAction *button = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Button 1" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
    {
        NSLog(@"Action to perform with Button 1");
    }];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; //arbitrary color
    UITableViewRowAction *button2 = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Button 2" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                    {
                                        NSLog(@"Action to perform with Button2!");
                                    }];
    button2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; //arbitrary color

    return @[button, button2]; //array with all the buttons you want. 1,2,3, etc...
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// you need to implement this method too or nothing will work:

}
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return YES; //tableview must be editable or nothing will work...
    }
```

Comment: Welcome and plz right mark clicked on this question

Comment: BTW, could you please also say what is the right way to show these actions only when a user swipes across a cell but not click Edit button?

Comment: @Majotron Note that **tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath: is only available in iOS 8.0 and later**. If you must support iOS7 or earlier, then this won't work! On iOS 7 you can either rely on 3rd party solutions or implement 2 undocumented iOS7 delegates - see [this gist and the discussion](https://gist.github.com/steipete/10541433). The latter will only allow you adding 1 custom button, though.

Comment: There is gesture mixing issue while i am swiping . It is called to other  button click in  tableview cell. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You CanTry also this code

```
.H File
{
    NSMutableArray *dataArray;

}


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *atableView;

@property(nonatomic,strong)  NSMutableArray *dataArray;

**`.M file`**


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Saurabh Sharma",@"Deepesh Jain",@"Ashish Sharma",@"Chandan",@"kanhaiya",@"Suchitra Bohra",@"Neha",@"Ghanshyam",nil];
    self.title = @"Move Rows";


    UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(editButton:)];

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:editButton];



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
    -(void)editButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)button
    {
        {
            if(self.editing)
            {
                [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
                [atableView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
                [atableView reloadData];
                [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
                [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
            }
            else
            {
                [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
                [atableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
                [atableView reloadData];
                [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
                [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];

    }

        }

    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;

    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [dataArray count];
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        static NSString *cellIdentifair=@"cellIdentifair";
        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifair];

        if(cell==nil)
        {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifair];
        }


         cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        return cell;

    }

    #pragma delete row in table view
    - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
        return 10; // This is the minimum inter item spacing, can be more
    }
    - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }

    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [tableView endUpdates];
        NSLog(@"Methods called when row is deleted");
    }

    #pragma Move Table View Delegte


    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return YES;
    }
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
    {
        NSString *item = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
        [self.dataArray removeObject:item];
        [self.dataArray insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    }
```

Comment: The snippet above is messy (you are mixing collection view delegates and table view delegates, using old ObjC syntax), and does not address the original question either.

Answer (score 1):

Works in Swift as well.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
        var completionButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal,
                                                    title: "Complete",
                                                    handler: {(action, index) in
                                                      /* Completion Code */
                                                      println("Complete")})
        completionButton.backgroundColor = .lightGrayColor()
        return [completionButton]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also for iOS 11 you should use

`- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` - for right swipe

and

`- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` - for left swipe

For ex.:

```
- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIContextualAction* action = [UIContextualAction contextualActionWithStyle:UIContextualActionStyleNormal title:@"Title" handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL)) {
        // Do something
        completionHandler(YES);
    }

    UISwipeActionsConfiguration * actionsConfiguration = [UISwipeActionsConfiguration configurationWithActions:@[action]];
    return actionsConfiguration;
}
```